# Why does X Server look for the ast driver?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, xorg

I'm attempting to start X.Org X Server 1.20.13 on a headless Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS server, so that I can use a GPU to display a remote desktop. I've previously gotten an xfce desktop to display without a GPU, but was unable to change resolution.

Issuing `sudo startx` via a remote SSH session gave me the following:

```
X.Org X Server 1.20.13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: linux Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux research-1 5.4.0-100-generic #113-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 3 18:43:29 UTC 2022 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.4.0-100-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ro maybe-ubiquity intel_pstate=disable
Build Date: 14 December 2021  02:14:13PM
xorg-server 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Mar 10 12:19:08 2022
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
pci id for fd 48: 1a03:2000, driver (null)
MESA-LOADER: failed to open ast: /usr/lib/dri/ast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
failed to load driver: ast
(II) modeset(G7): Initializing kms color map for depth 24, 8 bpc.
xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down .(II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Apparently, X Server expects to find driver `ast` at `/usr/lib/dri/ast_dri.so`, which doesn't exist. This is discussed somewhat in https://github.com/tbsdtv/linux_media/issues/240, but the discussion gives no indication as to what `ast` is and what it does.

(1) What is this `ast` driver, and why does X Server want to use it?

(2) Does `ast` have anything to do with the `xserver-xorg-video-ast` package? (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/xserver-xorg-video-ast)

Comment: AST is short for ASpeed Technology, a Taiwan based IC-design company. In this context it's about a server's graphics chip, indeed, and the package you mentioned is probably what you need to install.